# Swiftmailer exception doesn't catch in Symfony2 controller

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I am developing a simple mailing application with Gmail account as host.It works like a charm but the problem rises when send() function throw an exception.
I see that try catch statement can't handle the exception.
It doesn't work even when I use Global exception class.
this question discussed in somewhere also .

for example :

[Catch swiftmailer exception in Symfony2 dev env controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495804/catch-swiftmailer-exception-in-symfony2-dev-env-controller)

or

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/SlEzg_PKwJw

but they didn't reach a working answer.

My controller function code is :

```
    public function ajaxRegisterPublisherAction()
    {

//some irrelevant logic

     $returns=  json_encode(array("username"=>$username,"responseCode"=>$responseCode));


    try{
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('hello world')
        ->setFrom('jafarzadeh91@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('jafarzadeh991@yahoo.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView('AcmeSinamelkBundle:Default:email.txt.twig',array('name'=>$username,"password"=>$password))
        );
      $this->container->get("mailer")->send($message);

    }
   catch (Exception $e)
    {

    }



    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($returns,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));


    }
```

The response that sent from above code that  I receive in firebug console is :

```
{"username":"xzdvxvvcvxcv","responseCode":200}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    .
    .
Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?]
    .
    .
</html>
```

and I catch  my hairs because I don't know why the kernel handle the exception in continue of my json object?

when I comment this line:

```
 $this->container->get("mailer")->send($message);
```

the exception doesn't occur and I have a valid json in client side.(that is matter-of- course although)
I changed `Exception` to `\Exception` or `\Swift_TransportException` or even `Swift_TransportException` ! but no good result.

Comment: Did you try `Swift_SwiftException`? In the file it says "Base Exception class."

Comment: i mean 'Exception' by "Base Exception class"

Comment: I tested with "Swift_SwiftException" and "\Swift_SwiftException" now.It doesn't work

Comment: do you use the spooler?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by spooler but I exactly do the setting in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html except that I intentionally inactive openssl extension in php.ini in order to rise a sample exception!! thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

When you do `$this->container->get("mailer")->send($message);` the email message is not being sent at that point if you have spooling turned on. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html

If you have the default setting of `spool: { type: memory }`, the `\Swift_TransportException` will be thrown during the kernel termination phase, after your controller has exited.
One way around this is to turn off the spooling (but then your users might have to wait while the email is sent), or you can make your own eventlistener to handle the exception. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: this problem belongs to so many times ago.at the final we didn't able to solve the problem and so used another mailing library.unfortunately I don't know if your solution working or not now

Answer (score 2):

you need to beat the event dispatcher before it send back an exception, so listen to these kind of events and silence them, though i think this is a BAD way to deal with it

```
class SuchABadRequest implements \Swift_Events_TransportExceptionListener{

    /**
     * Invoked as a TransportException is thrown in the Transport system.
     *
     * @param \Swift_Events_TransportExceptionEvent $evt
     */
    public function exceptionThrown(\Swift_Events_TransportExceptionEvent $evt)
    {

        $evt->cancelBubble();

        try{
            throw $evt->getException();
        }catch(\Swift_TransportException $e){
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

inside the controller

```
$mailer = $this->get('mailer');

$mailer->registerPlugin(new SuchABadRequest());
```